# Selenium Server not starting up

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium

I have a server running Ubuntu 14.04.3 and am trying to get selenium working on it. I thought I had it running but when I stopped the service and tried starting it up again it just hangs

```
10:16:34.447 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
10:16:34.494 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.95-b01
10:16:34.494 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-71-generic amd64
10:16:34.515 INFO - v2.52.0, with Core v2.52.0. Built from revision 4c2593c
10:16:34.620 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
10:16:34.620 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
10:16:34.620 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
10:16:34.621 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
10:16:34.622 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=MAC, browserName=safari, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
```

Any ideas how I can debug/get it to work?

**Edit**

I'm using the following command to start the server

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar
```

I also intend to use Phantomjs as the driver.

Comment: Please post a command you use in order to run the node. What driver do you intend to use?

Comment: @MarkBramnik I'm a total noob when it comes to this but hopefully I've updated the original post that answers your questions

Answer (score 0):

Please try to specify a driver which will actually run your tests.

For example, for the chrome driver:

1. Install it ([from here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/))
2. Assuming chromedriver is in the current directory, Run:
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -port 4545

Of course you can change the port if you wish :)